# How to sort timestamps in the dictionary object

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a LRU cache and creates an object and check which item is added first by looking at the timestamps as follows.

import Foundation

```
class Item : Comparable 
{
    var timeStamp : Date
    var value : Int

    init(_ value: Int)
    {
      self.value = value
      self.timeStamp = Date()
    }
}

func < (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
    return lhs.timeStamp < rhs.timeStamp
}

func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
    return lhs.timeStamp == rhs.timeStamp
}

var item1 = Item (1)
var item2 = Item (2)
var item3 = Item (3)

var items = [1: item1 , 2 : item2, 3: item3]
items = items.sorted(by: {$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending})
print(items)
```

I am getting the following issue:

> error: value of tuple type '(key: Int, value: Item)' has no member
>   'date' items = items.sorted(by: {$0.date.compare($1.date) ==
>   .orderedDescending})

Then I need to sort and find the earliest timestamps in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `<` operator to compare `Date`s.

```
let sortedItems = items.sorted(by: {$0.value.timeStamp < $1.value.timeStamp})
```

I wouldn't recommend implementing `Comparable`, since even though my might want to sort your items based on simply their timestamps in some scenarios, it seems like you should take into consideration the `value` as well, especially for equality checking in other scenarios.

If you really only need to check `timeStamp` for comparison, you can make `Item` conform to `Comparable` and shorten your closure for `sorted`.

```
extension Item: Comparable {
    static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.timeStamp == rhs.timeStamp
    }

    static func < (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.timeStamp < rhs.timeStamp
    }
}

let sortedItems = items.sorted(by: {$0.value < $1.value})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just implement `Comparable` protocol for `Item`, or, maybe more useful
`[1: Item(1),2: Item(2),2: Item(3),].sorted { $0.value.timeStamp < $1.value.timeStamp }`